# Restore maximized/normal window after launching minimized app in QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qsettings

I have a problem with my Qt app. I can save and restore qeometry of my app without any problem. The problem is when I try to saveGeometry of maximized app in close event and after that I try to start the some app minimized (something like "Run mimimized on startup"). When I do that and I clicked icon on a taskbar the window is open as normal window (not maximized).

I can image (and write) some workaround but with all Gui logic it's easy to do some mistake that I prefere some native way. I'm looking for something like parametr when I could set that window after minimalization should be maximized or normal.

I don't have this problem when I start app maximized, next I minimize window and again maximize. In this case everything is ok. Problem is only on startup.

It look like small detail but it is big think if we think on app which people use everyday and they can't have everyday the some window.

EDIT:

After few hours I give up.
Here is my workaround. Not deeply tested yet, but mayby somebody needs it in the future.
I'll edit it if I find some error or better solution.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QSettings>
#include <QCloseEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), settings("MyCompany",     "MyApp") {
    settingsReaded = false;
    startMinimized = true;

    if(startMinimized) showMinimized();
    else show();
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
    showMinimized();
    event->ignore();
}

void MainWindow::readSettings() {
    restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry").toByteArray());
    settingsReaded = true;
}

void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent * event) {
    bool isActive = (event->type() == QEvent::ActivationChange && isActiveWindow());

    //load settings on first window activation (click on icon of minimized window or
    //open window if we have startMinimized = false
    //settingsReaded - determine that the settings was loaded only once.
    if(isActive && !settingsReaded) {
        readSettings();
    }
}
```

Comment: May sound silly, but can you launch full screen then fire your own minimize event to minimize it?  I can't think of hardly any apps that actually start totally minimized with no flashes...

Comment: Unfortunetly the flash isn't acceptable. I not sure that I correctly understand what you say. If you mean that you can't find example of apps which don't flash and start minimized then I think good example is uTorrent (I have tested this: no flash and work as I wish my app work).

Comment: I'm just saying that I'd like to be one of your users...  Sounds like you've got your goals in the right place.  (by app, I don't mean tray app, I mean something like a web-browser, say firefox.  Go ahead really play with it.)   From there - it seems like you'd have to take tight control of the first "un-minimize" operation of a newly started app.  (Forcibly putting in the right maxi parameter basically)  Is that really so invasive?   -- unless an invisible flash is possible somehow, set invisible and do the flash/window setup part--